# Jquery .sortable() with div is not working

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have created simple div, tying to rearrange using JQuery sortable.
[`Eample`](http://jsfiddle.net/h6xq0as1/1/)

The problem in the above example is, rearranging is working from bottom to top, means moving **C** between **A** and **B** is working fine, but moving top to bottom, means **A** between **B** and **C** is not working. Using list it is working fine. Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: actually your example code worked for me both ways

Comment: It is not working for me, I updated question with image.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with div(s). Please, check carefully.

Comment: It is not working for me, updated with image, but from bottom to top it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Add some `height` to your divs:

```
div {
  height: 18px;
}
```

EDIT (div.grid and immediate children)

```
div.grid > div {
  height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working. But i have deep internal div's and which auto height and many dynamic elements will add, so i cannot set height. Any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Updated. Try that. I also recommend using https://jqueryui.com/sortable/